# How to fill color in nsbox on nsslider movement?

Tags: cocoa

I want to fill color in an `NSBox` on slider movement.
I am using the following code.

```
-(IBAction)slider1move:(id)sender {
    [self.box setFillColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: ([self.slider1 floatValue])/255.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0]];   
}
```

Please correct me. I have three sliders in my application with each correspond to red , green and blue color.

How do I fill the color in the box on slider movement based on the current value of slider.
Like if my slider showing value of 50 the box should be half filled with red color if it is for red color.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you've met the requirements listed in `NSBox`'s `setFillColor:` documentation:

> Functional only when the receiver’s box type (`boxType`) is `NSBoxCustom`
>   and its border type (`borderType`) is `NSLineBorder`.

Assuming that's not the problem, a quick guess would be that you may need to call `setNeedsDisplay:` on the box to get it redrawn with the new color.

Comment: @Justin Boo 's answer from May 10 catches the actual problem -- `setNeedsDisplay:` is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Look at Your color, You set fully transparent color - **alpha to 0.0** that's why Your color it's not changing.

Change Your color to alpha 1.0 like this:

```
[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: ([self.slider1 floatValue])/255.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]
```